# What is "Cloud SQL connection error 2" on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

**Please vote up this issue with the App Engine / Cloud SQL team:** https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11898

I'm using Go on App Engine to access Google Cloud SQL using https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql as my driver. As I am adding a number of transactions, I get this error:

`Cloud SQL connection error 2`

Searching for it on Google doesn't return any results. What does that mean? I'm getting the error when trying to start a transaction.

My code works most of the time and only fails intermittently, so I'm confident that it isn't my code or SQL statements.

**UPDATE**:

- Restarting the database doesn't seem to make a difference
- I tried using an alternate MySQL driver `github.com/ziutek/mymysql` and got the exact same results.
- I also eliminated transactions as a source of the problem. I got an error just running a simple query using an index with a single join, returning 1 row.
- This happens with only a few concurrent queries

Comment: It seems a driver specific connection error. You may want to look at code error messages (https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=connection+error) or ask for help to driver's developer.

Comment: That error phrase doesn't appear anywhere in the driver codebase, so I can only assume that it is passing through an error that it's receiving from Cloud SQL. I could be wrong though.

Comment: I switched to using github.com/ziutek/mymysql/ and get the same error, so it's definitely not a driver error.

Comment: How frequent errors are ? How many concurrent queries/transactions ? Did you tried enabling Cloud SQL logging to look for connections errors?

Comment: The errors happen with a single query, and it happens inside and outside of transactions. Do I have to use the general_log flag to see connection errors or is there another way?

Comment: Yes, enable general_log = On and set log_output = TABLE

Comment: I haven't seen the error since a few days after I posted this. It seriously feels like something was going wrong with Cloud SQL that day.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar issues using Go on App Engine with Cloud SQL that seemed to be related to the creating too many connections to the cloudsql instance. I changed my code to create a single connection to the db during init which I reused throughout the program and seems to work, similar to what is [recommended here](http://go-database-sql.org/accessing.html).

Comment: I am reusing an instance level db variable. FYI, according to the Google App Engine Limits section on https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sizeqps, you are limited to 12 simultaneous connections per instance, regardless of the instance size. In your init function, you should probably call db.SetMaxOpenConns(12) so that Go manages your pool properly.

Comment: Please vote up this issue at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11898

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same issue. It appeared out of nowhere. Restarting the database through GAE helped for about half an hour, but then the problem returned.
I've updated my driver and the issue seems to have gone away:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/
git pull
```

Edit: The issue came up again after that, but this time I think it was caused by the server creating a lot of transactions and not rolling them back when an error happened. Thus a lot of outstanding transactions were created, leading to a deadlock. There were "timeout" errors for a while, and then "Cloud SQL connection error 2" came back. So another suggestion is look at what happens before you start getting that error. It might just be a symptom of something else.

Comment: I went through the same process, restarting the database, looking at the driver, seeing if transactions were involved, and nothing seemed to consistently influence the results...

Comment: Please vote up this issue at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11898